# Download FTP file to client w/ Readfile()

Tags: php, download, ftp, readfile

I'm building a web based file management interface for our clients, where I am attempting to facilitate a download from a remote (FTP) server to the client without downloading to the local web server first.

I've found that `Readfile()` does exactly what is needed, working perfectly for both web based downloads as well as from public FTP servers. The problem is that when specifying credentials via the FTP url, it apparently no longer works. I've found other reports of this online but thus far no solutions or workarounds.

```
$file_url = 'ftp://username:password@198.2.148.130/198.2.148.130%20port%2025665/server.properties';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Is there any workaround methods that would make this operate as expected? I am stumped as to how this can be fixed, where it seems like a bug moreso than a limitation.

Comment: Actually with the approach you show above you _are_ downloading the file to the server first, then relaying it on to the client.

Comment: About your specific question: take a look at php's ftp extension and use a temporary file.

Comment: I apologize, I should have been more clear. The approach I am using doesn't result in the client having to wait for the download to complete before it starts for them. It is only storing it in memory on the server, not writing it to a file.

Comment: @arkascha I do not think you are answering the question. I'm pretty sure the OP knows that the file is not downloaded directly to the client.

Comment: @BrettPowell *"no longer works"* means what? What does it do? What error (if any) do you get? - Your code works for me!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I did not write an answer, I made a comment. Since I am pretty sure that I have seen all sorts of people asking questions without knowing what they were doing. Sorry, if that annoys you.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The file it downloads on the client has the contents "failed to open stream: FTP server reports 550 The system cannot find the file specified." The similar report I found is from 2001 but describes the same issue http://marc.info/?l=php-general&m=99741707821411

Comment: What's the `198.2.148.130%20port%2025665` in your URL? That seems suspicious. - Shouldn't the URL be `ftp://username:password@198.2.148.130:25665/server.properties`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That part is the root folder name on the FTP server for that client. It is the IP/Port of their server in the format "x.x.x.x port 12345"

Comment: If you paste that URL to a web browser, does it work?

Comment: Yeah, pasting the URL I have in the script directly into the browser works perfectly, why I suspect the problem is either Readfile() or perhaps something unusual I am missing elsewhere (such as %20 not being read right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL-encoded spaces (`%20`) in the URL seems to the culprit.

Just use literal spaces:

```
$file_url = 'ftp://username:password@198.2.148.130/198.2.148.130 port 25665/server.properties';
```

It's perfectly valid to specify the credentials this way in PHP FTP URL wrapper.

Comment: Strangely I could have sworn I have already tried that twice, yet it is in fact working now. I guess after saying it in the comments I should have tried again but thank you!

Comment: As per your update to the answer, is there a similar alternative in the php ftp url wrapper that starts an automatic download on the client? That was my main concern with all other approaches I found, where it required downloading to the web server before the client download would start.

Comment: That's too complex question to be answered in a comment. But no, you cannot initiate a direct transfer from FTP server to client from your web server. All you can do is to use `ftp://` URL directly on the web page. But then you will have to reveal the credentials to the user.

Comment: That is what I thought but was a bit confused from the wording at the end. Thank you again for helping me hunt that down, Readfile was perfect and I was worried it was a bug/limitation.